# Azure B2C custom policy ROPC: how to read the username before trying to validate the password?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to create a custom policy to support a migration scenario in which an app uses ROPC as authentication flow.
The journey should work as following:

- Get the username from the ROPC request
- Check if the user has to be migrated
- If no

  - Validate the password against the local B2C
- If yes

  - Validate the user on the remote B2C
  - Copy the password in the local B2C
  - Flag the user as migrated

The flow works as expected if I use a standard Sign-in flow. When I try to adapt it for the ROPC Oauth flow (converting all the validationTechnicalProfiles in a user journey, as stated in [Azure AD B2C Custom Policy with Username Logon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726916/azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-with-username-logon)), the flow simply refuses to start if the first orchestration step does not refer to the "ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-OAUTH2" (which is not what I want, since before authenticating the user I need to check if it has to be migrated). From the appinsights log, the flow fails with the message:

```json
{
  "Kind": "Action",
  "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.MoveFirstOrchestrationStepHandler"
},
{
  "Kind": "HandlerResult",
  "Content": {
    "Result": true,
    "Statebag": {
      "ORCH_CS": {
        "c": "2023-09-10T10:16:25.7263383Z",
        "k": "ORCH_CS",
        "v": "1",
        "p": true
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "Kind": "Action",
  "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.InvokeValidationProfileDirectHandler"
},
{
  "Kind": "FatalException",
  "Content": {
    "Time": "10:16 AM",
    "Exception": {
      "Kind": "Handled",
      "HResult": "80004001",
      "Message": "The method or operation is not implemented.",
      "Data": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I've defined a test Claim provider that is:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Claim Transformation</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="ClaimTransformation-ExtractUsername">
      <DisplayName>Extract user name</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Dev_ToBeMigrated" DefaultValue="true" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Dev_SourceB2CTenant" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Username}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>  
</ClaimsProvider>
```

this user journey fails with the previous error:

```xml
<UserJourney Id="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials">
  <PreserveOriginalAssertion>false</PreserveOriginalAssertion>
  <OrchestrationSteps>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="CheckUserToBeMigrated" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ClaimTransformation-ExtractUsername" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="ResourceOwnerFlow" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-OAUTH2" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep> 
    
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
</UserJourney>
```

this one returns a token instead

```xml
<UserJourney Id="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials">
  <PreserveOriginalAssertion>false</PreserveOriginalAssertion>
  <OrchestrationSteps>


    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="ResourceOwnerFlow" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-OAUTH2" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep> 
    
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="CheckUserToBeMigrated" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ClaimTransformation-ExtractUsername" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
</UserJourney>
```

Do you have any working example of an ROPC policy that do some prechecks before authenticating against the local B2C? Or do you know how to solve the error I'm facing right now?